# bootstrap.css className is not effecting the styling of the website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I am trying to use bootstrap.css to go through a tutorial on react but for some reason the styling is not being updated, I feel like this is probably an issue with my webpack.config but I have tried numerous fixes with nothing working, here is my current config:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, './public'),
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.js'),
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
          },
        ],
      },

      {
        test: /\.(scss)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
            loader: 'css-loader',
            loader: 'saas-loader',
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: function () {
                return [require('precss'), require('autoprefixer')]
              },
              modules: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
}
```

and also my package.json

```
{
  "name": "trend-dot-com",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "TBA",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties": "^7.10.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.5.3",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --progress"
  }
}
```

and finally my js code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 1,
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="test">
        <span className="badge badge-primary m-2">{this.formatCount()}</span>
        <button className="">Increment</button>
      </div>
    )
  }

  formatCount() {
    const {count} = this.state
    return count === 0 ? 'Zero' : count
  }
}

export default Counter
```

Ive made sure to import the bootstrap.css in my index.js as well. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Here is my index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {render} from 'react-dom'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import App from './components/app.jsx'

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not imported it :)
You have to install it with npm or another module and import him :)
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

Comment: I did import it in my index.js? Am i suppose to import it somewhere else as well?

Comment: In the component you need to use bootstrap

Comment: Okay I also imported it in the components counter file and its still not working?

Comment: So you have not install bootstrap with npm. I tested that and it's work. I always use it looool

Comment: I’m using yarn for my environment? And I did yarn add bootstrap and it’s in my package.json? So that may be why but idk

Comment: The only answer I can tell it's : You have not imported it so find a way to import it ;) many tutorials ^^

Comment: Respectively I think the issue is somewhere else,
I have followed this exact guide https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-bootstrap/,
and done everything listed with no luck.

Comment: Hum. I told you to put bootstrap in the file where you component is. And you put it in your index.js so it's not working...

Comment: It wasnt because i was putting it in the wrong file, it was because of my webpack.config but i figured it out, thank you anyway